# why this jQuery object undefined?

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(function () {
            var mainimagepanel = $("#blah1");
            var postimagepanel = $("#blah2");
   });
```

both object exist on the page where i run my $. can someone show me why i got exception mainimagepanel is not defined

the exception caused in Firebug or Chrome dev tool. so someone can tell me reason and how i can check that a input control exist on both.

Comment: I'm guessing there's more code here that you're not showing. Where are you referencing `mainimagepanel` later on?

Comment: Are you trying to access those variables outside of that function?

Comment: no i just exsitence with Chrome dev tool and firebug and both give me exception that not defined. if  i pass var mainimagepanel = $("#blah1");mainimagepanel  then it's show me the right things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variables are declared inside the anonymous function, and that is their scope. They do not exist outside that function. To fix it, you can do something like:

```
var mainimagepanel, postimagepanel;

$(function () {
  mainimagepanel = $("#blah1");
  postimagepanel = $("#blah2");
});
```

It is however usually good advice to limit your variables so that they exist in the tightest possible scope.

Comment: sje397 is absolutely right both that this will fix it, and that it's a bad idea. Take a quick look at my answer to get a better sense of why.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my guess. I'll try to go a bit further in depth than the other answers have. You have this:

```
$(function()
{
    var mainimagepanel = $('#blah1');
    var postimagepanel = $('#blah2');
});

// ... bunch of code ...

mainimagepanel.show(); // oh no!
```

You've just run into something called **scoping**. Specifically, you've run into something called **function scope**.

Let's run a couple of experiments.

```
var a = 'hello';

var myfunc = function()
{
    alert(a);
    var b = 'goodbye';
    alert(b);
};

alert(a); // pops 'hello'. good, we expected that.
myfunc(); // pops 'hello', then 'goodbye'. good, that seems right too.
alert(b); // error. because b was declared inside of myfunc, it doesn't exist out here.

var myfunc2 = function()
{
    a = 'greetings';
};

myfunc2();
alert(a); // pops 'greetings'. because myfunc2 is inside of our main code here, it can see the a out here.

var myfunc3 = function()
{
    var a = 'salutations';
    alert(a);
};

myfunc3(); // pops 'salutations'. that seems reasonable, that's what we just set it to.
alert(a);  // pops 'greetings'. huh? turns out, because we var'd the a this time, it made a *new* a inside of myfunc3, and when you start talking about a, it assumes you want that one.
```

Hopefully, that makes things clearer. The long and short of it all is, you want to do this instead:

```
$(function()
{
    var mainimagepanel = $('#blah1');
    var postimagepanel = $('#blah2');

    // ... put your code here ...
});

// ... instead of here! ...
```